# changing the timestamp format of elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to load log records into elasticsearch (7.3.1) and showing the results in  kibana. I am facing the fact that although records are loaded into elasticearch and a curl GET shows them, they are not visible in kibana.

Most of the time, this is because of the timestamp format. In my case, the proper timestamp format should be basic_date_time, but the index only has:

```
# curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/og/_mapping'
{"og":{"mappings":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date"},"componentName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}}}%
```

I would like to add format 'basic_date_time' to the @timestamp properties, but  each try I do is either not accepted by elasticsearch or does not change the index field. 
I simply fail to get the right command to do the job.

For example, the simplest I could think of,

```
Z cr 23;curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/og/_mapping' -d'
{"mappings":{"properties":{"@timestamp":{"type":"date","format":"basic_date_time"}}}}
'
```

gives error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={@timestamp={format=basic_date_time, type=date}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={@timestamp={format=basic_date_time, type=date}}}]"},"status":400}%
```

and trying to do it via kibana with

```
PUT /og
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp":    { "type": "date", "format": "basic_date_time" } 
    }
  }
}
```

gives

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
        "reason": "index [og/NIT2FoNfQpuPT3Povp97bg] already exists",
        "index_uuid": "NIT2FoNfQpuPT3Povp97bg",
        "index": "og"
      }
    ],
    "type": "resource_already_exists_exception",
    "reason": "index [og/NIT2FoNfQpuPT3Povp97bg] already exists",
    "index_uuid": "NIT2FoNfQpuPT3Povp97bg",
    "index": "og"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I am not sure if I should even try this in kibana. But I would be very glad if I could find the right curl command to get the index changed.

Thanks for helping, Ruud

Comment: I must admit I probably have misunderstood the problem. The symtom is recent log records not showing up in kibana. I assumed it had to do something with the date format, but after some tests, I suspect the timezone being the reason. Maybe kibana thinks the records are in the future and does not show them. Timestamps look like "@timestamp":"2019-09-12T00:47:12.165+00:00". When I create records that are 12 hours old, they are shown. So it is not a date problem, but a time problem.

Comment: In in the time picker in Kibana try to extend the time interval displayed to further in the past and further in the future. That way you can see if it's a time issue or not.

Comment: I did not realise this was even possible. I changed the time specification to 'next 5 hours' and indeed: it showed me the 4 records that were missing.  But now: what can I do so that kibana has the same idea of what 'now' means as the software that generates the log records?

Comment: You can configure the timezone that Kibana is supposed to work in by going to Management > Advanced Settings.

Comment: I realized that the log records specified the wrong time zone. Since the time zone is CEST, the log records should specify +02:00. With that correction, kibana shows them correctly.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either via curl like this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/og/_mapping' -d '{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "basic_date_time"
    }
  }
}
```

'

Or in Kibana like this:

```
PUT /og/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": { 
        "type": "date", 
        "format": "basic_date_time" 
    } 
  }
}
```

Also worth noting is that once an index/mapping is created you can usually not modify it ([very few exceptions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings)). You can create a new index with the correct mapping and reindex your data into it.

Comment: That give the error message{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [@timestamp] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [@timestamp] has different [format] values]"}]

Comment: Yeah, once created you can usually not modify a mapping (very few exceptions). You'll can create a new index with the correct mapping and reindex your data into it.

Comment: I deleted the index and the index patterns. But the above error message keeps occuring. Given my real problem is solved, I should quit trying to change the format. Thanks Val for your help.

Comment: I'll accept it Val; I did not do it yet because what really helped me was your comment at my question. I should be able to accept that, instead of this answer....

Comment: Cool, I added that comment to my answer as well!